# ADO.NET how to add parameter if I use connection class in a separate file?

Tags: c#, ado.net

ADO.NET how to add parameter if I use class in a separate file?

Class:

```
class SQLconnect
{
    public static void Sql(string Command_Text)
    {
        string connectionPath =
            "Data Source=USER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionPath);

        Connection.Open();

        SqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
        Command.CommandText = Command_Text;
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Parameter:

```
        SQLconnect.Sql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[work] ([name],[code])VALUES(@name, @code)");

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@name";
        param.Value = nameTextBox.Text;
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Text;
        //   Parameters.Add(param);


        param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@code";
        param.Value = codeTextBox.Text;
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Text;
        //   Parameters.Add(param);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to update your SqlConnect.Sql() method to accept a set of parameters:

```
class SQLconnect
{
    public static void Sql(string Command_Text, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        string connectionPath =
            "Data Source=USER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionPath);

        Connection.Open();

        SqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
        Command.CommandText = Command_Text;

        if(parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0) 
        {
          foreach(var p in parameters)
            Command.Parameters.Add(p);
        }


        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Then your calling code would be something like this:

```
    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
    param1.ParameterName = "@name";
    param1.Value = nameTextBox.Text;
    param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Text;

    param2 = new SqlParameter();
    param2.ParameterName = "@code";
    param2.Value = codeTextBox.Text;
    param2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Text;

    SQLconnect.Sql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[work] ([name],[code])VALUES(@name, @code)", param1, param2);
```

Comment: SQLconnect.Sql_gs("INSERT INTO [dbo].[work] ([name],[code])VALUES(@name, @code)",param1,param2);

None of the overloads of the method "Sql" not accept "3" argument

Comment: Does your Sql() method signature look like this:

public static void Sql(string Command_Text, params SqlParameter[] parameters)

Note the params keyword...

Comment: Well, if the other class is in other library, you need to add a reference to `SqlClient` in the other library with the solely purpose of pass the `SqlParameter()`.  Must be another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version hope it helps

```
public class SqlConnect
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }
    public string CommandText { get; private set; }
    public SqlParameterCollection Parameters { get; private set; }

    public SqlConnect(string connectionString, string commandText)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        CommandText = commandText;
        Parameters = null;
    }

    public SqlConnect(string connectionString, string commandText, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
        : this(connectionString, commandText)
    {
        Parameters = parameters;
    }

    public int Execute()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = CommandText;

            foreach (var sqlParameter in Parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
            }

            int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            return rowsAffected;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class for Database connection...then create a properties for each parameter like follows

```
public class StudDataAccess
{
    public string connectionString = "Data Source=USER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    public int pStudId
    {
        set;
        get;
    }
    public string pStudName
    {
        set;
        get;
    } 
    public void NewStudent()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddStudent", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pStudId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pStudName;            
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }  
}
```

Here we created two parameters id ,name so you can set values of it from the class where you need to insert,select data. as follows by creating object of that class

```
        StudDataAccess objDataAccess = new StudDataAccess();
        objDataAccess.pStudId =Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        objDataAccess.pStudName = TextBox2.Text;           
        objDataAccess.NewStudent(); //Call addstudent store procedure with parameters
```